# Anyway to select data entered based on date it was enter in Excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I want to create a macro that begins with selecting a section of data from a worksheet... however I want this selection to include only the data that was entered on the same day the macro is run. For example (simplified) if there are 10 rows of data already in the excel sheet, and I enter 3 more rows of data today, I want it to be that when I initiate the macro, it selects only the last 3 rows of data. Is this possible? (For this to serve the purpose I am looking for, the macro is always run after the data is input, and there will in practice be closer to ~200 rows of data enter each time... thus I cannot go through and individually type in the date next to the row or something like that).

Comment: You could track which rows have been processed by having your macro update another column.  So, for example, you update columns A~B.  The marco processes these and leaves a marker in column C.  This could be a date time stamp.  You'll be able to restart from the last row with an empty column C.  In addition the status of each row is saved along with the workbook.

Comment: @destination-data Is there an excel function which can assign the date data is entered?

Comment: Yes.  Use `Now()`.  **EDIT** This returns the date.  Excel does not tag cells with a *last updated* property.  Unless you add this functionality yourself it is not available.

Comment: Unless you tag the rows with a date or some other "flag" there is no built-in function which will return the date that information was added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is store the last row processed in the names collection of the worksheet.  So when you start your macro you get the last row updated.  When your macro finishes you set value of the name.

> lastRow = getLastRow("Sheet2")
>
> setLastRow "Sheet2"

```
Function getLastRow(SheetName As String) As Long
    Dim value As String

    On Error Resume Next
        value = Worksheets(SheetName).Names("LastRow").RefersTo
        getLastRow = CLng(Right(value, Len(value) - 1))
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Function

Function setLastRow(SheetName As String) As Long

    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Worksheets(SheetName)
        lastRow = .Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Names.Add Name:="LastRow", RefersTo:=lastRow, Visible:=False
    End With
    
End Function
```